# SVD based method for predicting missing values in future experiments

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I would like to pose my question in terms of a hypothetical example, where I have a matrix:

```
11 12 13...1m 
21 22 23 ..2m
.  .  .    3m
.  .  .  .  .
11 n2 n3 .  nm
```

The matrix has no missing values. Each column corresponds to one experiment and each row corresponds to a particular measurement parameter ( eg: temperature @ point 1, temperature @ point 2... Pressure....)

next, I conduct a New experiment, and I measure most parameters but not all n parameters. I want to estimate the missing parameter(s) in my New experiment.

Is there a formula based on SVD/PCA to calculate the missing value in my New experiment based on my 'training' matrix?

Are there any better machine learning / statistical methods to perform this calculation ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PCA is a dimensionality reduction technique $\Rightarrow$ It is useful to transform our data to a space with fewer dimensions (retaining the highest amount of variance as possible), thereby we can't estimate new dimensions based on it. A technique that can do this sort of estimation is a [Variational Autoencoder](http://www.cs.us.es/~fsancho/?e=232). This technique first encodes the data in a lower dimensional space and then decodes it to a higher dimensional space. A paper which may be related to the problem you described is [AutoRec](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~u5098633/papers/www15.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Javier!